# Returning a pointer from a function using template in c++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, linked-list, program-entry-point

Line inside main `Node<int> *head = takeInput()` is giving error ***no matching function for call to 'takeInput()'***. Can you help me and tell me whats the mistake I am doing here so that I wouldn't do it in future. Thanks!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Node{

public: 
    T data;
    Node *next;
    Node(T x){
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
        }
    
};

template<typename T>
Node<T> * takeInput(){
    T data;
    cin>>data;
    Node<T> *head = NULL;
    Node<T> *tail = NULL;
    
    while(data != -1){
        Node<T> *newNode = new Node(data);
        
        if(head == NULL){
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }else{
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail = tail->next;
            }
        cin>>data;
        }
    return head;
    }
    
int main(){
    Node<int> *head = takeInput();
    cout<<head->data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has flaws;

Your compare `head == NULL`, it's always be null, every time function runs because, you assigning NULL `Node<T> *head = NULL`; at start of function.

And using [`NULL`](https://cpp4arduino.com/2018/10/26/why-cpp-programmers-dont-use-null.html) not recommended in c++, use [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr);

Took liberty and modified your function. there is many ways you can implement below function, for now i took it below way, I am not saying it's the best way.

```
template<typename T>
void takeInput( Node<T>*& head, T val ){

    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>( val );

    if ( head == nullptr )
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        Node<T>* tmp = head;

        while ( tmp->next != nullptr ) tmp = tmp->next;

        tmp->next = newNode;

    }
}
    
int main()
{
    Node<int> *head;
    
    takeInput( head, 10 );
    takeInput( head, 20 );
    takeInput( head, 30 );

    std::cout<< head->data << std::endl;
    std::cout<< head->next->data << std::endl;
    std::cout<< head->next->next->data << std::endl;

}
```